# Why is UPnP so slow?

Tags: iphone, streaming, upnp, dlna

So, I have a UPnP enabled TV (Samsung), a UPnP server (tried several), and a UPnP control point (right now, PlugPlayer on the iPhone).

Using PlugPlayer to load up my library (just a few items for testing) on the iPhone takes a few seconds. This part is not so bad... However, trying to use the PlugPlayer as just a control point, with the TV as renderer, is very slow! It takes up to a minute before something happens on the TV, when it even works...

Why is UPnP so difficult to get right, when you want to be more advanced than having the renderer being the control point?

Comment: Sadly as much as I think it's a good question, I am failing to see how it falls within the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) when both iPhones and TV's are off topic for Super User? Can you please update this to make it more specific?

Comment: The iPhone and TV was just examples... I could do the same with 3 pc's and the slownessness of it would be just the same... And btw, iPhone was the most popular tag for this post...